# How to get the tray icon highlighted when an email in a local folder is received?

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, messaging-tray

When I get a new email in my inbox folder, the tray icon changes to blue (in Ubuntu 12), but when I use a filter to move the email to a local folder, the tray icon doesn't change!

How can I solve this? Thanks!

(It's being cross-posted from the [Thunderbird forums](https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/how_to_highlight_the_tray_icon_when_get_an_email_in_a_local_folder?rfm=1), where I had no response)

Comment: I've [notified](https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/how_to_highlight_the_tray_icon_when_get_an_email_in_a_local_folder#reply_10185102) the forum about the crosspost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In thunderbird, go to edit, preferences, tick "show in the messaging menu" and select "for messages in all folders". When moving a message by using the filter, it's not possible.

Comment: I have that already checked and the icon is not getting highlighted :(

Comment: do you have in the TB filter other action apart from moving it to the other folder? May be you have for example to also mark it as read?

Comment: Nop. That's the only filter I have. The destination folder is under Local Folders, maybe should I create it in a different location? Thanks

Comment: Do you have normal operation when a new mail comes and is not moved by the filter? For me, when a mail is received and TB decides it is junk (and I have set to move it to junk), then the highlight is off, which is right for me. Probably when the message is moved it is not working. You can try probably in the filter to put copy instead of moving to see the reaction.

Comment: I could copy it but I don't want to have the email twice. The rule is pretty simple, when the message is matched, it's moved to a folder. Nothing more, nothing else.

Comment: Hi Diego, I checked it myself also. If you move it TB does not give the signal to highlight it. A solution is you see the notification (local folders has new message...) if you enable the "show an alert" option in general preferences.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested and it seems not to be possible. Edit your question saying "When moving a message, it's not possible" and I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks.